# Missing Modules for EAR Deployment in Wildfly

Tags: java, deployment, ejb, wildfly, ear

I'm working on deploying an EJB project as an EAR in Jboss Wildfly 18. The layout of my ear currently looks like this:

```
 Person.ear->
    META-INF->
        jboss-deployment-structure.xml
        MANIFEST.MF
        ...
    lib->
        Common.jar
        BugReport.jar
    Person-ejb.jar
    Person-web.war
```

with a jboss-deployment-structure.xml like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
  <deployment>
      <dependencies>
         <module name="Common.jar" export="TRUE"/>
         <module name="BugReport.jar" export="TRUE"/>
      </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

When I try to start up the server the deployment fails with the following error:

```
15:00:20,234 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.module.service."deployment.Person.ear".main: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.module.service."deployment.Person.ear".main: WFLYSRV0179: Failed to load module: deployment.Person.ear
    at org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ModuleLoadService.start(ModuleLoadService.java:116)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1739)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1701)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1559)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1363)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: com.tura.optics.common
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.addPaths(Module.java:1266)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.link(Module.java:1622)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.relinkIfNecessary(Module.java:1650)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModule(ModuleLoader.java:299)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModule(ModuleLoader.java:283)
    at org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ModuleLoadService.start(ModuleLoadService.java:93)
    ... 8 more
```

I have tried defining dependencies via the jboss-deployment-structure.xml and via the MANIFEST.MF with no success. I also tried naming the dependencies with the package name (i.e. com.tura.common) since I have seen both formats used. Still no luck. I'm not quite sure what I'm missing here; it seems like I am following the expected layout. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Did you try deployment.Common.jar as module name ? Also I don't think a jboss-deployment-structure.xml is required in this case.

Comment: if you just need jars that are in your lib folder of ear on classpath, you don't need jboss-deployment-structure.xml at all. can you paste contents of your application.xml which would control this

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of using `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` as the reference of JAR libraries within the EAR is covered by the Java EE platform specification ([JSR 366](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=366))

In fact, it should work with your current EAR structure, removing the `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`

The section **EE.8.2.1 Bundled Libraries** provides several ways to make JAR libraries available to modules.

1. You can add a reference to the JAR file with a Class-Path entry in the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file of the module using the library (not the EAR).

For example, if person-ejb.jar depends on lib/Common.jar and lib/BugReport.jar, you could add:

```
Class-Path: lib/Common.jar lib/BugReport.jar
```

in the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF inside de file Person-ejb.jar. Same for Person-web.war

2. JAR files put in the `<library-directory>` of the EAR are made available to all modules. And `<library-directory>` by default is directory lib, so, as you have both Common.jar and BugReport.jar inside the lib directory they should be already available to Person-ejb.jar and Person-web.war.

You can provide a deployment descriptor `application.xml` in the META-INF directory of the EAR file, and override the `<library-directory>`. An example `application.xml` file for your EAR would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/application_8.xsd" version="8">
    <display-name>Person.ear</display-name>
    <module>
        <ejb>Person-ejb.jar</ejb>
    </module>
    <module>
        <web>
            <web-uri>Person-web.war</web-uri>
            <context-root>/person</context-root>
        </web>
    </module>
    <library-directory>lib</library-directory>
</application>
```

Comment: @pbuchheit could you try it?

Comment: @ areus I was finally able to come back to this and try your suggestions. I removed the jboss-deployment-structure.xml and added the <library-directory> tag. Now when I try to start up the server I get the error: "Module may not be a child of the EAR's library directory. Library directory: lib, module file name: lib/Common.jar". Thoughts?

Comment: Is lib/Common.jar declared as a `<module>` inside the `application.xml`? it shoudn't